# Web Audio API equivalent for iOS, Android, React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, audio, web-audio-api

Web Audio API allows us to play synthesized sound. What if you're working with React Native? For example, consider a mobile app that is a piano. How do I make the sound?

**I am not looking for a library that helps to play or record audio files.**

Ideally, I want https://tonejs.github.io/ for iOS/Android

Comment: At time of writing I believe your only option is still the native APIs for real-time DSP. JUCE may be the better option

Comment: Android is fine as you could just make a progressive web app, iOS is the sticking point.

Comment: I see ... think I will try out audio sprites in this case

Answer (score -1):

The [expo-av](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/av/) package tree-shakes the unused platform code for iOS and Android when it's built for web. Current platform compatibility includes Android Device, Android Emulator, iOS Device, iOS Simulator, and Web.